# roboguice get currenty activity context

Tags: android, roboguice

How do i inject the current `Activity` context into my object? I've tried using the `@Inject` annotation when declaring the instance variable as well as in the constructor of the object but it seems RoboGuice is injecting the wrong one or creating a new `Activity` object.

```
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): [ 07-09 13:58:02.110 21352:21352 W/System.err ]
        1) null returned by binding at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): but parameter 0 of com.myapp.utility.NavigateAppAction.<init>() is not @Nullable
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): while locating roboguice.inject.NullProvider<android.app.Activity>
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:131)
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): while locating android.app.Activity
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): for parameter 0 at com.myapp.utility.NavigateAppAction.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-09 13:58:02.110: WARN/System.err(21352): while locating com.myapp.utility.NavigateAppAction
```

Answer (score 0):

If you @Inject Activity or Context, it should inject the current activity because RoboGuice ships with a binding for Activity and Context.  However, if you try to @Inject MySpecificActivitySubclass, you'll need to set up your own binding.

Comment: whenever i try to @Inject the current Activity i get the error i've added to the OP

Comment: I've noticed if i try to inject a Context via the constructor of my class, the Application context gets injected, not the Activity

Comment: has this been fixed yet?